# What to call someone who always says "nothing" on most things you ask?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am referring to the kind of person, when you ask him something he will say "nothing" all the time. When you ask them the question again or why they responded like this, they say "forget it" or "because it's an irrelevant question" (even though it really is not a relevant question to you.) They only respond like that on questions, not constantly on everything you say throughout the conversation, though.

Comment: I think this is inherently Too Broad. The *unresponsive* person may be *distant, taciturn, unhelpful, reserved, reticent, reserved, aloof, detached, quiet,* etc.

Comment: This question is better asked on psychology/ behavioral science Q&A.

Comment: Has this fellow a name? Use that.

Answer (score 2):

We can say that the person is very *dull*.

Or

We can say that the person is *pessimist*.

Pessimist-

> A tendency to stress the negative or unfavorable or to take the gloomiest possible view

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is [*laconic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/laconic):

> Using or marked by the use of few words; terse or concise. See Synonyms at *silent*.

The word comes from the Greek Lakōn, "a Laconian, a person from Lacedaemon," the name for the region of Greece of which *Sparta* was the capital. The Spartans, noted for being warlike and disciplined, were also known for their lack of ornamentation and the *brevity of their speech.* It is this quality that English writers still denote by the use of the adjective laconic, which is first found in this sense in 1589.

One of the most famous examples of *laconic speech* is found in a communication between Philip of Macedon and the ephors (leaders) of Sparta.

Philip, wanting to subdue all of Greece, but hoping to avoid a fight with the Spartans, brought his great army to the borders of Laconia, and sent a message to Leonidas.

“‘If you do not submit at once,’ he threatened them, ‘I will invade your country. And if I invade, I will pillage and burn everything you hold dear. If I march into Laconia, I will level your great city to the ground.’

The ephors sent Philip an answer. When he opened the letter, he found only one word written there.

> "If.”

Neither Philip nor Alexander ever captured Sparta.

Comment: Forget the answer.. the story is worth reading lol.

Answer (score 1):

The person you describe could be said to be *unresponsive,* or *a very private person.*